# Inserting XSRF header token in Hydra

Tags: authentication, web-application, linux, hydra, dictionary

I'm trying to break a login form with Hydra. The site is built with the Angular framework, and an XSRF token must be sent through the header and through the POST request.

I notice that the XSRF token is already being sent by Hydra through the request, but it isn't being sent through the header.

Is there any way to include such *dynamic* token in the header with each auth attempt?